JOLT Transformation: replacing text
I am trying to find the solution for transforming the below JSON data. Mainly I want the date which is having / to be replaced with -.
The replace logic which I tried below is not working. Can someone help me in this?
It seems like replace with modify-overwrite-beta is not working.
Input JSON
{
  "certificates": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "description": "description1",
      "mapping": [
        {
          "date": "DEC/2023",
          "code": "ABC1",
          "rating": null,
          "scope": [
            "scope1",
            "scope2",
            "scope3"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "description": "description2",
      "mapping": [
        {
          "date": null,
          "code": "ABC1",
          "rating": null,
          "scope": [
            "TBD"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Expected output:
{
  "certificates": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "description": "description1",
      "validity": "DEC-2023",
      "code": "ABC1",
      "rating": null,
      "scope": [
        "scope1",
        "scope2",
        "scope3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "description": "description2",
      "validity": null,
      "code": "ABC1",
      "rating": null,
      "scope": [
        "TBD"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "code": "ABC1"
}

Tried the below spec
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "name": "certificates[&1].name",
          "description": "certificates[&1].description",
          "mapping": {
            "*": {
              "*": "certificates[&3].&",
              "date": "certificates[&3].validity"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "code": "ABC1"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "validity": "=replace(validity,'/','-')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Getting below output


Yet, you can use modify-overwrite-beta transformation along with split and join functions such as :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "mapping": {
            "*": { //handle multiple characters(i.e."/","-"..etc.) at once
              "date": "=split('/',@(1,&))",
              "validity": "=join('-',@(1,date))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the original "date" attribute
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "mapping": {
            "*": {
              "date": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "", //current value of the whole JSON 
      "@certificates[0].mapping[0].code": "code" //add an extra attribute
        //without an hardcode  
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Hope the below Jolt Spec will be helpful for you.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "mapping": {
            "*": {
              "isDateNotNull": ["=notNull(@(1,date))", false],
              "splitDate": "=split('/',@(1,date))",
              "customDate": "=concat(@(1,splitDate[0]), '-',@(1,splitDate[1]) )"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "code": "ABC1"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "*": "certificates[&1].&",
          "mapping": {
            "*": {
              "isDateNotNull": {
                "false": {
                  "@(2,date)": "certificates[&5].validity"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@(2,customDate)": "certificates[&5].validity"
                }
              },
              "*": "certificates[&3].&"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "certificates": {
        "*": {
          "date": "",
          "customDate": "",
          "splitDate": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


